# 2019 Jeep Cherokee won't start

Tags: battery, starting, jeep, voltage, cherokee

My car is a 2019 Jeep Cherokee on Friday my car wouldn't start. On my dashboard it said low battery voltage. I have had the battery a year and a half. I had someone jump it off and it started up. I took the battery to Auto Zone to have it checked and they said it was fine. I drove it Saturday and Sunday with no problem. The battery voltage stayed around 13.9. Today Monday it wont start and the voltage read 10.3. Could this be a bad battery or something else? Help

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Battery tests are esoteric and often give false negatives. It's your battery. Try a warranty claim wherever you bought it. If it's a junky value battery, like from Walmart, well, you get what you pay for. I'd just suffer the extra cost and get a battery that will actually last 5+ years.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest it is most likely a bad battery. It sounds like you might have an intermittent problem with a cell within the battery which is shorting out. 10.3vdc is about what I'd expect when this happens.

If the battery is only 1.5 years old, it should still be covered under warranty where you can get it replaced for free. I'd pull this string and get it done or you're going to continue to have the same issues.

Comment: Thank You for your response. I will have battery checked and possibly replace and see if this works.

Comment: While testing the battery, have the alternator tested too. Autozone can test them in the vehicle or bench. Be sure the drive belt is tight, not loose.